# Not seeing Clone and Download Button

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub. I am looking Clone and Download button.
But Unfortunately, not getting it. Somehow got lost.

It is showing green button as <>Code.
Can anyone guide me how to find it?

I tried to look for setup. But did not find it.

Comment: can you share more details? like screenshot, which repository are you referring to etc

Comment: Have you tried clicking the green "<> Code" button? On my end, that opens a pop-up with the URLs to clone over SSH and HTTPS, plus a link to download as zip. Do you know how to clone a repository from a URL?

Answer (score 0):

I only see those buttons/options when I am logged in to GitHub:

[image: buttons]

So first, double-check if you are logged in / authenticated when browsing https://github.com.